# Opencv-Python input array error

Tags: python, arrays, opencv, video-capture

I recently started to explore OpenCV and I am very knew to this. I am having trouble displaying an scaled video frame inside a original video frame. Hope this makes sense. everything works fine but when i tried to change the color of the scaled video, I get an error. Here is my code hopefully its self explanatory.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    #"ret" returns a frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    #Draw a rectangle at given location
    cv2.rectangle(frame,(500,80),(800,380),(0,255,0),5)

    #takes a sample of the frame marked by the rectangle area(y,x)
    face_track = frame[80:380, 500:800]
    #converts the sample to gray
    grayscaled = cv2.cvtColor(face_track,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    #threshold range of sample
    retvl, threshold = cv2.threshold(grayscaled,125,125,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

    #overwrites/display a new area with the sample taken by face_track in the left top corner of the frame
    frame[0:300, 0:300] = threshold

    #displays the frames captured by cap
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    #cv2.imshow('frame',threshold)

    #if key stroke is 'q' break and terminate 
    if cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xff == ord('q'): 
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

the following is the error:

> frame[0:300, 0:300] = threshold
>   ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (300,300) into shape (300,300,3)

If I change it to this:

> frame[0:300, 0:300] = face_track

It works. But is not what I want.

Also if I output threshold instead, as such,
`cv2.imshow('frame',threshold)`,
it would also work. But again not what I want.

Is there any other function besides `cv2.cvtColor` that does not change the array shape.

Answer (score 0):

convert thresh gray to BGR

cv2.cvtColor(threshold,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

Comment: Nice, it worked! thanks. Would you mind to explain what was happening? @bluekid

Comment: color image has 3 channel , gray scale 1

Answer (score 0):

The error is that you are doing single channel matrix(8UC1) operations on a three-channel matrix(8UC3).

To solve this problem you either need to **convert the single channel matrix(grayscale) to three-channel(BGR)** or do single channel matrix operation on a single channel matrix. To do this in python openCV:

```
cv2.cvtColor(threshold,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
```